# Facebook Graph API Error - Feed action request limit reached

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook-graph-api, facebook

I am using graph api for facebook to post message on the wall. I am able to post the message on the wall successfully but after certain number of posting i am able to get error on console

```
{"error":{"message":"(#341) Feed action request limit reached","type":"OAuthException"}}
```

I think this error is occurred due to too many post on the wall. So how to avoid this error. Does anyone have an idea as what might be going wrong here or how I can better debug this problem?

Comment: Hi am getting this message from last three days. and not able to post on wall from last three days. Every day same error. Can you please help me ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Had a similar experience and came across this post while searching for a reason as to why FB was limiting the number of posts. We were actually doing some testing of sharing news articles from an app authorized with FB and since we were sharing the same link over and over again, it marked them as spammy and decreased our limit to 7!

Here are some guidelines. http://edoceo.com/notabene/facebook-api-oauthexception-341

If you ever happen to be testing, make sure you are not doing the spammy tests because that would decrease the limit on the app.

Answer (score 13):

This seems to answer your question:
[Does Facebook SDK have a limit for posting to a wall](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4880036/does-facebook-sdk-have-a-limit-for-posting-to-a-wall)

"Facebook does enforce limits on how many posts per day your app can complete. It is not a hard and fast number, and varies by app and over time depending on the app's behavior. If your app produces posts of low quality (spammy), as measured by how many times people comment on, like, or hide your app posts, then Facebook will decrease your daily limit. These limits are expressed as "buckets" and can be seen on the Insights page for your app.

You will get an error message back from the Facebook API if you have exceeded the limit. The error number is 341 and the description is "Feed action request limit reached". This is enforced on a per-user, per-day basis."

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer is to post fewer things. Facebook is attempting to limit your app--you shouldn't be trying to dodge the limit. It's there for a reason. No one likes apps that spam their wall anyway.