# Only 7 shares a day? OAuthException 341

Tags: facebook-graph-api, limit, facebook-oauth

We are finalizing a new site wich uses a Facebook-app to log in users.

We have of course made quite a few test posts to Facebook to test functionality, but have now encountered this error: "OAuthException: (#341) Feed action request limit reached"

We get this after just 7-9 FB shares in one day using the Facebook API. Probably because of the content of the messages (e.g. "Testing comment", "lorem ipsum" etc.). We are guessing this has been picked up as "spam", thus reducing the limit.

But hey. It's not good. It is now very hard to test because of the limit. And what will happen when we launch? A 7-shares-a-day maximum?

Thanks a whole lot for any advice here ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook Graph API Error - Feed action request limit reached](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779379/facebook-graph-api-error-feed-action-request-limit-reached)

Answer (score 1):

"Facebook does enforce limits on how many posts per day your app can complete. It is not a hard and fast number, and varies by app and over time depending on the app's behavior. If your app produces posts of low quality (spammy), as measured by how many times people comment on, like, or hide your app posts, then Facebook will decrease your daily limit. These limits are expressed as "buckets" and can be seen on the Insights page for your app.

You will get an error message back from the Facebook API if you have exceeded the limit. The error number is 341 and the description is "Feed action request limit reached". This is enforced on a per-user, per-day basis."

Had a similar experience and came across this post while searching for a reason as to why FB was limiting the number of posts. We were actually doing some testing of sharing news articles from an app authorized with FB and since we were sharing the same link over and over again, it marked them as spammy and decreased our limit to 7!

Here are some guidelines. http://edoceo.com/notabene/facebook-api-oauthexception-341

If you ever happen to be testing, make sure you are not doing the spammy tests because that would decrease the limit on the app.